# How to resolve failed to load resource:net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: browser

I get the following error message:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

While images get loaded in my website.
The Images gets loaded without any problem in my LAN but when I try to view the image on my website which is deployed on WAN.

Comment: Did you try to check url in HTML page and open image directly? It is probably problem with firewall in your network

Comment: Thanks dude....i check it ..that problem was in path..